# WKWebView loads HTML content too slowly in iOS 9 using swift

Tags: javascript, ios, swift2, ios9, wkwebview

I have been trying to integrate the `WKWebView` as a subview of another `webview` in a UIViewController. I've been able to load the content and communicate properly with the `swift` and `JavaScript`. However, the loading time of the `HTML` content without any data manipulation takes close to 2 seconds.

I have also tested loading the `WKWebView` with just an empty body of `HTML` without any scripts loading. This still takes 600 milliseconds to load.

The time taken difference between `viewDidLoad` and the `webView` (`webView`: `WKWebView`, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!)** Is 600 ms, if even the HTML contains an empty body.

***viewDidLoad function of the ViewController***

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    NSLog("started - %@.%@", String(self.dynamicType), __FUNCTION__)
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let wkConfiguration: WKWebViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let userController: WKUserContentController = WKUserContentController()
    wkConfiguration.userContentController = userController
    wkConfiguration.processPool = VCWKWebView.wkProcess
    self.wkWebView = VCWKWebView(frame: self.webView.bounds,configuration: wkConfiguration)
    if let wkWebView = self.wkWebView {
        self.webView.addSubview(wkWebView)
        wkWebView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: wkWebView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.webView, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: wkWebView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.webView, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        webView.addConstraints([height, width])
        //wkWebView.delegate = self
        wkWebView.navigationDelegate = self
        wkWebView.loadContent()
    }
    
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    
    NSLog("ended - %@.%@", String(self.dynamicType), __FUNCTION__)
}
```

VCWKWebView class:

```
class VCWKWebView: WKWebView  {
    
    static let wkProcess: WKProcessPool = WKProcessPool()
    
    private static let _url: NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("index", ofType: "html",inDirectory:"www")!)

    private static let _accessUrl: NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("www", ofType: nil)!)

    
    func loadContent(){
        NSLog("started - %@.%@", String(self.dynamicType), __FUNCTION__)
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            self.loadFileURL(VCWKWebView._url, allowingReadAccessToURL: VCWKWebView._accessUrl)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        NSLog("ended - %@.%@", String(self.dynamicType), __FUNCTION__)
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration) {
        super.init(frame:frame, configuration:configuration)
    }
    
    convenience init(frame: CGRect){
        let wkConfiguration: WKWebViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        self.init(frame:frame,configuration:wkConfiguration)
    }
    
    deinit{
        print("deinit of VCWKWebView is called")
    }
}
```

Comment: Found anything useful?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem replacing UIWebView with WKWebView for some javascript intensive web pages.  WKWebView is much slower which seems contrary to all the advice about them.  Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Ever figure out any fixes for slow loading in WKWebView?

Comment: What about stating the webview once, and reuse it across your application? You could have it ready beforehand.

Comment: @chq how does one create a webview in one place, and then use it elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two ways.

#1. Optimize your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code.

#2. You need to implement WKWebView delegate functions.
And you need to show the Webview content after loaded the webview content.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens because of CSS used in rendering web page. It is default behavior when loading page locally. We can also consider that in first load, UIWebview doesn't have cache to this and create cache for that page.

Please share your html part as well so I could check